# Asynchronous parsing of a subprocess' output in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, subprocess

I'd like to execute a subprocess from a Python3 script and look for a specific line in stdout.

Here is a dummy script which emits lines:

```
# emitter.py
import time

for i in range(1, 11):
    time.sleep(1)
    line = f" [Emitter] - The time is {i}"
    if i == 5:
        line += " KILL ME NOW"
    print(line)
```

And here is the snippet which demonstrates my usecase:

```
# worker.py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "emitter.py"],
                     bufsize=1,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     text=True)

for i in range(10):
    try:
        out, err = p.communicate(timeout=1)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        continue
    else:
        lines = out.split("\n")
        if any("KILL ME NOW" in line for line in lines):
            p.kill()
            break
```

Currently the worker script simply times out without getting any output from the emitter.

I would like to parse the lines or the subprocess output asynchronously, so I can kill the process when my program reaches a certain maturity :)

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved it.

The problem was that the emitter did not flush the output.

The correct emitter code is as follows:

```
# emitter.py
import time

for i in range(1, 11):
    time.sleep(1)
    line = f" [Emitter] - The time is {i}"
    if i == 5:
        line += " KILL ME NOW"
    print(line, flush=True)  # Note the flush
```

This can be parsed by a simpler worker:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "emitter.py"],
                     bufsize=1,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     text=True)

for line in p.stdout:
    print(line)
    if "KILL ME NOW" in line:
        p.kill()
```